# capture packets then drop packet IPS system

Tags: c#, c++, matlab, neural-network, libpcap

Is there any possible way in windows to "drop" packets like a true IPS(intrusion prevention system) similar to iptables in unix.

Also if im using matlab is there a way to "capture packets on the network" and feed them into a neural net? Matlab on windows that is.

Im struggling to understand how libpcap can "capture" data but yet you cant "drop" data in real time?

Rather annoying snort cant do it, snort only acts as a IDS on windows but IDS/IPS on linux due to it being able to right rules to iptables.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows 7/Vista you can use the Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) API to do simple packet filtering, similar to what to can achieve with iptables.  The API is somewhat verbose, however.

For more complicated filtering, e.g. say URL filtering that payload parsing/inspection, you'll need to either (1) write a device driver such as a WFP callout driver, or (2) use a third party package that can divert packets to user-mode applications.

For the latter there is [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/divert.html) (GLPv3) and [WinpkFilter](http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=7) (commercial license).  Both packages are C/C++ so you'd need to write an appropriate MatLab binding.  *Disclosure: I am the author of WinDivert.*

*Warning Technical*: Packages like Winpcap do not, and can not, drop packets because of the type of driver it uses (NDIS protocol driver, to be precise).  Protocol divers only see copies of packets and have no way to block the original packet.  For this they'd need to re-implement the Winpcap driver as a NDIS IM or LWF driver.

Comment: Can I be able to use it on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Actually What I am creating is set Functions for my IDS and this will be in dll file. So Can you guide me using Windivert for Windows?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Yes you can use it with VS2010, but this discussion is best taken offline.  Please send me an email.

Comment: Many thanks @Basil for sharing this out! I would like to use your library on my solution "C#Win7" to make some sort of filtration that **drops outgoing packets except a specific ports during application running**, the application will run under **administration privilege** on the client side, the clients should add it to the exception list of their antiviruses; question is **will using this library still works when other firewall software enabled?** like if user has Symantic firewall running, does the library driver will be installed and dropping packets using WinDivert will function probably?

Comment: @Jalal I have not tested this, but I don't foresee any problem using WinDivert with other firewall systems.

Comment: OK, thanks again for such an amazing library, I have searched the net for days to find any clue on how to create a custom firewall in C# before I have seen WinDivert, for now I have no choice but to test it and I will start to write a C# wrapper for it.